# Do you know how to add VEE and VCC power teminals to op-amp in Cadence that will be fit for simulation?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, non-inverting

[image]

This is the op amp that comes with Cadence. I need to add a capacitor to the \$V_{CC}\$ wire and ground the \$V_{EE}\$ wire. However, there is clearly not a VEE or VCC on this op amp. Also, I know that I could manually alter the VEE and VCC in the properties but it won't help. I need Those VCC and VEE wires.

Is there a script that I need?

Comment: Many years ago when I used OrCAD, it could be done by doubleclicking on the part and marking pins visible/invisible.. If I recall correctly.

Comment: did you use a script to edit the sim?

Answer (score 1):

The Correct answer to this is, Click "Add Libraries Icon" in the "Place A Part Tab" and the search for the "EVAL" library and add uA741 op amp. the two offsets (OS1 and OS2) can safely be ignored.